# Making a simple wordcloud in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

```
#Loading Packages

library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

library(RColorBrewer)

speech="/Users/GregDuncan/Desktop/bills.txt"
modi_txt = readLines(speech)


modi<-Corpus(VectorSource(modi_txt))


modi_data<-tm_map(modi,stripWhitespace)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,tolower)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,removeNumbers)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,removePunctuation)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,removeWords, stopwords(“english”))


tdm_modi<-TermDocumentMatrix (modi_data) #Creates a TDM

TDM1<-as.matrix(tdm_modi) #Convert this into a matrix format

v = sort(rowSums(TDM1), decreasing = TRUE) #Gives you the frequencies for every word

Summary(v)



wordcloud (modi_data, scale=c(5,0.5), max.words=1, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, “Dark2″))
```

So I'm trying to make a word cloud out of a document. I'm trying to run it with Rscript and I run into a issue such as this

```
  enter Error: unexpected input in "modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,removeWords, stopwords(?"
Execution haltedcode here
```

and

```
   unexpected input in "wordcloud (modi_data, scale=c(5,0.5), max.words=1, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, �"
```

I'm pretty new to R, so I'm trying to just learn the basics. I don't know if someone with more experience can see the issue quickly

Comment: it must have thrown error for the "english" you need to be sure its properly mentioned. remove the quotes and retype it.

Answer (score 0):

Note the changes below, and it should run.  I used the data set `crude` from the tm package.

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

library(RColorBrewer)

data(crude)
modi_txt <- crude

modi<-Corpus(VectorSource(modi_txt))


modi_data<-tm_map(modi,stripWhitespace)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,tolower)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,removeNumbers)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data,removePunctuation)

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data, removeWords, stopwords("english")) # NB quote marks were wrong.  This can happen if you copied from Word, for example

modi_data<-tm_map(modi_data, PlainTextDocument) # NB: added this call

tdm_modi<-TermDocumentMatrix (modi_data)

TDM1<-as.matrix(tdm_modi) 

v = sort(rowSums(TDM1), decreasing = TRUE) 

summary(v) # NB need lower case "s"

wordcloud (modi_data, scale=c(5,0.5), max.words=1, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35,
           use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))  # NB had to fix quotes for "D...
```

The result is very odd here, but you may want to experiment with your `wordcloud` arguments.

[image]

Comment: I got all my text in a bills.txt
How do I get my text into this crude object? You seem to just of made it

Comment: Did you try something like modi_txt <- scan("/Users/GregDuncan/Desktop/bills.txt", what = "character")?  Then proceed.  I used the data set to demonstrate because you did not provide any of your text.  If you enter dput(modi_txt) in the console or command line, and then cut and paste the result into your question, others can reproduce your actual text.